# folder permission 777 not working

Tags: php, linux, directory, file-permissions

In hosting server we set a 777 permission for folders, but we can't write the files in folders, and also we check the is_writable php code to check the permission,

```
if (is_writable($dir)) {
    echo $dir, ' is writable';
  } else {
    echo $dir, ' is NOT writable';
 }
```

but its showing    "is NOT writable"

Comment: If PHP says it's not writeable then it's definitely not writeable. No matter how much you may believe PHP made a mistake or lied to you; it didn't. You made the mistake somewhere; you just don't know it. `var_dump($dir)` if it's a relative path use `var_dump(realpath($dir))`. Confirm your doubts with facts.

Answer (score 1):

Check the selinux context **(command: ls -Z /directory_path)** of that folder.
It is suppose to be **httpd_sys_content_t** for apache http. If it is not set then change it to this.

> chcon -h system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t  /directory_path

Answer (score 0):

you can check your filename. or file path.

Bacuse your using style is correct.

Maybe a little careless. Thanks.

```
<?php
$file= 'try.txt'; 
if (is_writable($file)) {    
echo 'writable';
} else {    
echo 'not writable';}
?>
```